# Cassandra 4 and Cipher Suites

Tags: encryption, cassandra, cassandra-4.0

Trying out Cassandra 4 for encrypted internode communication.

Following settings are made in cassandra.yaml

```
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: all
    optional: false
    enable_legacy_ssl_storage_port: true
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: password
    require_client_auth: true
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: password
    require_endpoint_verification: false
    # More advanced defaults below:
    protocol: TLS
    store_type: JKS
    cipher_suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
```

However these ciphers are not being listed with `nmap --script +ssl-enum-ciphers -p 7000 <hostname>`

Have not seen this issue with earlier Cassandra 3.11.x.
Are there any further settings apart from cassandra.yaml which are being missed here for Cassandra 4?

Comment: Looking forward for some pointers here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see what's going on.  Before Cassandra 4.0, inter-node SSL traffic used port 7001.  However, Cassandra 4.0 allows both encrypted and unencrypted inter-node communication on port 7000...

...*unless* you explicitly enable the legacy SSL port...

```
enable_legacy_ssl_storage_port: true
```

Two possible solutions here:

- Run `npm` against port 7001, and you should see the available ciphers returned.
- Set `enable_legacy_ssl_storage_port: false`, restart, and the `npm` against port 7000 should work.